# How to make a board in android

Tags: android, gridview

I wonder if anyone could help me with this, I want to make 2 boards on a single activity in android, each board should be of size 10*10 (10 rows and 10 columns),one board will be clickable and the other view-able only.
I will be having 2 emulators, one for player 1 and the other for player 2..

I'll be able to press on player 2's board on my emulator,this will show at player's 2 emulator that his board was clicked at that specific cell, then he can press on his emulator at my board that is only view-able to him, and that will show on my emulator that my board has been clicked at that specific place..

I know it's a bit too long for a question haha, but I really need your help you guys, I was able to get the idea that it will be using GridView, but i'm facing lots of troubles, I'll be very thankful if you can help..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use GridLayout.
Actually for sample codes and example, I recommend getting samples in the SDK Manager and importing the APIDemos. It has many ways you can create your 10x10 grids/table/layout and so on.

Comment: Alright will try to do that, thanks a lot Calvin, your help is really appreciated :))